# How to make this operator= overload work?

Tags: c++, overloading, virtual, operator-keyword

I was experimenting with making the `operator=` be virtual, like so:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Base {
public:
    std::string field1;
    Base(std::string str) : field1(str) {}

    virtual Base& operator=(const Base& other)
    {
        field1 = other.field1;
        return *this;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    std::string field2;
    Derived(std::string str1, std::string str2) : Base(str1), field2(str2) {}

    virtual Derived& operator=(const Derived& other) override
    {
        Base::operator=(other);
        field2 = other.field2;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

However, this gives a compiler error, because the `Derived` function is not actually overloading anything, the signatures are different.

Is it possible to override the `operator=` to write code like this?

```cpp
Base* ptr = new Derived("old 1", "old 2");
Derived derived("new 1", "new 2");

*ptr = derived; // <- use the derived class operator= to assign both field1 and field2
```

Comment: The override is not being called because it is not overriding anything. The signature is different. The base class's parameter is `const Base&`, and the derived class's parameter is `const Derived &`, that gets passed to their respective `operator=`. To override a virtual function in the base class, the signatures must match. `operator=` does not get an exception to this rule.

Comment: Always favour using the `override` of `final` keywords for member functions you are _intending_ to override; if you make a mistake, the compiler can help you out. We only ever needed `virtual` for overridden virtual methods as a semantic notation before C++11 introduced these new keywords.

Comment: Yes you are right. My mistake. I just added the override keyword to the function and it is giving a compile error.

Comment: What's `*arr[1] = newBase` supposed to do, then? This doesn't work because it cannot work: it's *not safe* to override a method with another method that has a more specific argument type because someone might use it through the more general interface of the superclass with an argument type your overriding method cannot handle. Here, the correct behavior can only be decided by looking at the types of both the receiver and the argument, but `virtual` dispatch is only done on the receiver. The key words are ["double dispatch"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch#Double_dispatch_in_C++).

Comment: polymorphic `=` is about as bad an idea as polymorphic `==`. What happens when the parameters are of different types?

Answer (score 0):

This operator

```
virtual Derived& operator=(const Derived& other);
```

does not override the copy assignment operator declared in the base class.

You have to write

```
Derived& operator=(const Base& other) override;
```

That is the type of the parameter shall be `const Base &`.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    virtual A & operator =( const A & )
    {
        std::cout << "A::operator =\n";
        return *this;
    }
};

struct B : A
{
    virtual B & operator =( const A &a ) override
    {
        A::operator =( a );
        std::cout << "B::operator =\n";
        return *this;
    }
};


int main() 
{
    B b1;
    
    A &rb1 = b1;
    
    B b2;
    b2 = rb1;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
A::operator =
B::operator =
```

Comment: This allows `B` to `override` the operator. But then you still have to check to make sure that `a` is really a `B` instance before accessing any `B` members from it, eg: `B& operator=(const A& a) override { A::operator=(a); if (const B *b = dynamic_cast<const B*>(&a)) { /* use b as needed ... */ } return *this; }`